# silverlight deserialization issue if order is not provided in datamember attribute!

Tags: silverlight, wcf, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0

the silverlight is compaining "the formatter threw an exception when desealizing ...."

basically what i have come to conclusion is , that  , on the server's datamodel classes if datamember's order attribute is not defined , the silverlight formatter (and the server serialiser) does not work correctly.

when i used linq2sql to generate the model classes , they had order attribute and every thing worked fine

but when i used entity framwork , which does not has the order in datamember attribute the formatter complaint .

now , first solution is , how can i instruct the entity framework to put the order attribute of datamember

second is , that how do i make the formatter work if order is not present.

thanks

Jamal.

P.S
one more thing i found with entity framework generated classes is , there is an attribute in DataContract ,

```
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
```

while for linq2sql that attribute is not there

```
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
```

Comment: It doesn't depend on order, the problem must be somewhere else. Add full exceprion message to the answer.

Comment: hi and thanks for the response.i have figured out the problem . the issue was that if lazy loading is not disabled the datacontract serializer will load all the related entities and it childs entities and so on .... so i disabled the lazy loading on the context. but now one more problem has occured. i.e for each child entities i loaded using include and child's children are getting loaded on searialzing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the class(es) and more details about the exception, including the inner exception. If your class contains other classes try adding KnownTypeAttribute